# Infinite feof loop

Tags: php, perl, sockets

When using `feof` or `fgets` the script will keep running until the 1 minute max execution mark.

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalPort => '5000',
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    Listen    => 5,
    ReuseAddr => 1,
);

my $connection = $socket->accept();

$connection->send("\0"); # makes PHP send the contents

my $data = <$connection>;
if($data != "1234") {
    $connection->send("not accepted");
} else {
    $connection->send("accepted");
}

$connection->close();
```

PHP will **not** send the content until the 60 seconds has passed. When using `fread` it will pass the data (but will only get the `\0` back) almost instantly.

```
$socket = fsockopen('tcp://192.168.56.101', 5000); // virtualbox IP
fwrite($socket, '1234');

echo fread($socket, 128);

fclose($socket);
```

The above script will execute almost instantly but only get `\0`.

```
while(!feof($socket)) {
    echo fread($socket, 128);
}
```

Using the above script will not send any data until the 60 seconds is up on execution.

## Question

How do I get PHP to send data and retrieve all data from the perl socket without the 60 second execution timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is actually sending the data right away; the problem is Perl isn't doing anything with it. If you do this:

```
my $data = <$connection>;
print $data; #add this line
if($data != "1234") { ....
```

and then kill the PHP script with Ctrl-C (Windows -- don't know what the command is if you're using Linux), the Perl script will immediately output "1234". It's hanging up on the angle bracket operator because that is a readline (i.e. it's looking for a newline and never finding one). Either of the following got your code to work for me:

```
//in the PHP file
fwrite($socket, "1234\r\n");
```

or

```
#in the Perl file (instead of my $data = <$connection>)
my $data;
$connection->recv($data, 1024);
```

**Edit:** see comments below before just implementing a change. As hobbs mentions, recv is probably not the best choice, although it happened to work since it's not looking for a newline and the input is short. Sending a newline in some capacity (variant of the first suggestion) is probably the better option.

Comment: ... or have PHP send a newline, or use length-prefixing, or *some* way for the listener to know when it's actually received all of the data. `recv` isn't 100% correct here, although it will probably work just fine given such a shot iput.

Comment: @hobbs - `recv` is not totally reliable: agreed. I was more just trying to explain why he was seeing the script hang and showing that using a function that doesn't care about newlines was continuing the script successfully.